# How to add all the elements of a row/column selected by the user in a matrix (MIPS Assembly)?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am stuck in the b,c,d questions of this problem which ask me to set up a matrix of integers (memory alocated) and ask the user what to do:
a) Print the matrix.
b) Show element ubicated in the position array[i][j].
c) Add all elements of a row selected by the user.
d) Add all elements of a column selected by the user.
e) Add all elements of the matrix.

I have already tried to implement with a tutorial the row major representation where I used this formula:

address = base Address + (row Index * column Size + column Index)* data Size

So far I figured out how to do the diagonal sum, but I don´t know how to sum the rows and columns with the first address of the array[0][0] that I got with the row major representation.

In the question b). I have not found anything online about how to do it neither.

English is not my mother tongue, If you need something explained better let me know and I will try!

```
.text
    main:
            # Sum diagonal
    la $a0, mat
    lw $a1, size
    jal sumDiagonal
    move $a0, $v0                   
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

sumDiagonal:
    li $v0, 0   # sum = 0
    li $t0, 0   # $t0 as the index

    sumLoop:
    mul $t1, $t0, $a1   # t1 = rowIndex * colSize
    add $t1, $t1, $t0   #       + colIndex
    mul $t1, $t1, DATA_SIZE # * DATA_SIZE
    add $t1, $t1, $a0   # + base address

    lw $t2, ($t1)       
    add $v0, $v0, $t2   # sum = sum + mdArray[i][i]


    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # i = i + i
    blt $t0, $a1, sumLoop   # if i < size, then loop again

    jr $ra
```

The matrix is a 3x3 matrix which has 3 as all the values. If you want to see all the code check this pastebin file. https://pastebin.com/8619qHrL
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing loops, it is generally easier to completely decouple loop index (i) and address management (compute @ of array elements), instead of computing address from index at every iteration. It is easier to understand and more efficient (and this how compilers work).

To compute row or col sums, this may correspond to the following code

```
sumRow(int *mat, int size, int row){
  int sum
  for(int i=0, int *ptr=mat+row*size; i!=size; i++, ptr++)
      sum += *ptr
  return sum;
}

sumRow(int *mat, int size, int col){
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0, int *ptr=mat+col, int increment=size; i!=size; i++, ptr+=increment)
      sum += *ptr
  return sum;
}
```

Once you have the C code, implementation is straighforward. First compute the initial values, then loop over body+increment+test condition.

Here is a possible mips version.

```
sumRow:
#expects $a0 matrix, $a1 size, $a2 row to add
    li $v0, 0   # sum = 0
      # compute  address of first element
      # as ptr=matrix+rwnbr*size*4
    mult $a2, $a1   # rnbr*size
    mflo $t1        # get result from mult
    sll $t1, $t1, 2 # *4
    add $t0,$a0,$t1 # @ first element to add
    li $t1,0        # index=0

sumRowLoop:
    lw $t2,($t0)    # sum+=*ptr
    add $v0,$v0,$t2

    addi $t0, $t0, 4# ptr++
    addi $t1,$t1,1  # i++

    bne $t1, $a1, sumRowLoop   # if i != size, then loop again

    jr $ra

sumCol:
#expects $a0 matrix, $a1 size, $a2 col to add
    li $v0, 0       # sum = 0
       # compute address of first element to add
       # as ptr=array+colnbr*4
    srl $t1, $a2, 2 # colnbr*4
    add $t0,$a0,$t1 # $t0 @ 1rst element
    li $t1,0        # $t1 i=0
    srl $t3,$a1,2   # ptr increment in $t3 is size*4

sumColLoop:
    lw   $t2,($t0)  # sum+=*ptr
    add  $v0,$v0,$t2

    add  $t0,$t0,$t3 # ptr+=increment
    addi $t1,$t1,1  # i++

    bne $t1, $a1, sumColLoop   # if i != size, then loop again

    jr $ra
```

For getting element at address [i][j], you just have to compute (i*size+
j)*4 and add it to array address to get the element.

```
elementAt:
#expects $a0 matrix, $a1 size, $a2 i, $a3 j
    mult $a1,$a2     # size*i
    mflo $t0         # t0<-result of mult
    add  $t0,$t0, $a3# add it    +j
    sll  $t0, $t0, 2 # and *sizeof(int)
    add  $t1, $a1,$t0# matrix+i*size+j
    lw   $v0,0($t1)
    jr ra
```